# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Word can't be blank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given this code:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :definitions
end

class Definition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :word
  validates :word, presence: true
end

mysql> show columns from definitions_words;
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| definition_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| word_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I call:

```
word = Word.first
word.definitions.create!
```

I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Word can't be blank)
```

Comment: Why did you expect it to work?

Comment: In my opinion is ok and should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** Your relation on Definition class is wrong. It should be in plural! :words

**Second:** The validation is also wrong.It should be in plural too. e.g. validates :words

In this way, it expect that a field with name word not to be blank instead of the relationship.

Try to change you example code to:

```
word = Word.first
definition = Definition.new
definition.words = [word]
definition.save
```

Comment: Why do You think that bad naming convention cause this validation error ?

Comment: Is not a bad naming convention. I just think it was a misspelling. Thats why i suggested to change it.

Comment: I received: Validation failed: Words can't be blank

Comment: Can you post the migrations u made?

Comment: It is because of the validation. Since u are validating the association object, on creation it doenst have properly setd the first object since is not a one to one relation. I think There aren`t much options with this behavior you specified.

Comment: This is a quiet typical situation. I want to validate existence of associated many-to-many record. This looks like a some Rails bug.